# Not able to generate correct output in recursive function?

Tags: c++, loops, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that detects the number the negative integers in a stack recursively. Currently the snippet below is what I have, however it is not giving the correct answer so far. I tested with a stack of 11 elements with 7 negatives and got the output given below. There is definitely something wrong with the loop structure but I have not been able to pinpoint and fix it yet. Any help will be appreciated!

```
12356657235681623569772357137235729723574562357617235777623579372358096
```

My function below:

```
size_t r_func(stack<int> st1)
{   
    if(st1.size() == 0) return 0;
    int r = st1.top();
    st1.pop();
    cout << (r<0)+r_func(st1);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the function declaration too?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything if `st1.size()` is nonzero, even though you declared it to return `size_t`.  The numbers you're seeing is just random garbage from the stack.  (Suggestion: always compile with compiler warnings on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t r_func(stack<int> st1)
{   
    if(st1.size() == 0) return 0;
    int r = st1.top();
    st1.pop();
    cout << (r<0)+r_func(st1);
}
```

`r_func` is supposed to return a `size_t`, but if `st1.size()` is not zero then it won't return anything.  The compiler should've given you a warning about this!

To correct this, add a line that returns the number of negative numbers in your stack:

```
    ...
    st1.pop();
    const size_t neg_count = (r < 0) + r_func(st1);
    cout << neg_count;
    return neg_count;
}
```

**Edit**: To write this [tail-recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it's necessary to keep track of the size in an accumulator (here it's called `neg_accum`):

```
size_t r_func(stack<int> st1, size_t neg_accum = 0)
{   
    if (st1.size() == 0) {
        cout << neg_accum;
        return neg_accum;
    }
    int r = st1.top();
    st1.pop();
    return r_func(st1, (r < 0) + neg_accum);
}
```

Comment: After implementing the said changes, I got the output 12234556677 instead of 7. I used the same stack again for testing which has 7 negatives and a total of 11 elements.

Comment: Well yes, I assumed that's what you wanted!  If you put your `cout` inside the recursive function it will be called for *every element*.  If you don't want that, you need to pull the `cout` outside as Daniel L suggested.

Comment: Ah yea, I should have not put the cout in there, but yes, I want the function to just give me the number of negatives in the stack. So for the above mentioned example, I want it to output 7. Also as Daniel L suggested, his method would work however I want the function to be directly called without the use of cout.

Comment: Then you need to add a "wrapper" function that does the `cout`, or write it tail-recursively with an accumulator and call `cout` when the size reaches zero (which is really contrived because you may as well just use a while/for loop).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to c++. How would I attempt to write it tail-recursively?

Comment: [Tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) isn't specific to C++ or any language.  I've added an example of how it could be done with tail recursion.

Comment: Thanks! that helps. However is there a way to achieve the same functionality without adding an extra parameter(size_t in our case) or creating any more functions?

Comment: With recursion only, you can't.  Each function is self-similar so it's impossible to tell when you've "finished" recursing except when the list is empty.  But when the list is empty, you can't remember how many negative elements you've counted without an accumulator.

Comment: (You could of course cheat by using static variables though, but that's more of a hack.)

Answer (score 0):

As Rufflewind said, you should replace 'cout <<' with 'return' and call your function in this way: 'cout << r_func(st1);'